# ASP.NET MVC 2 Redirect all actions from one controller to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, redirect, global-asax

I have two controllers with the same actions and private methods. The second one is copied from the first.
I modified the second one, to perform better and now I want to route all the actions from the first controller to the second one.

How can I do this from Global.asax or some other way in a way that could let me keep the old code for fast switching?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a route like:

```
"mycontroller/{action}",
new{controller = "mynewcontroller", action="index"});
```

You could also just rename your controllers in the code.

Comment: If I rename the all the fast switching is lost

Comment: Ah, so by "fast switching" you mean you'd like a mechanism that will switch the implementation without having to recompile or restart the server? Try creating an admin controller that allows you to add and remove a route like the one shown above.

Comment: Yeah, that is just what I want, please post all the code of adding the new route.

Comment: @Floradu88: I don't have quick access to my code samples right now. I can try posting later, or you can look at how your Global.asax.cs file goes about adding the default route as an example.